# Recurring event in event_calendar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, calendar

I use [event_calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar) in my app, and I need to create repaeted ability for my event. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at ruby toolbox's category for [reoccurring events](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/recurring_events)?

Haven't used any, but the toolbox has done well by me =]